# How to add one property inside the aspect in the out of the alfresco content model i.e.applicationModel.xml

Tags: alfresco

I want to add a property inside an aspect in the Alfresco content model  `applicationModel.xml`.

How can this be done?

```
<aspect name="app:linked">
  <title>Marker aspect to indicate that the node has been linked.</title>
 </aspect>
```

Below property shouldbe addded inside above aspect.

```
<properties>
  <property name="app:links">
    <title>Links:::</title>
    <type>d:noderef</type>
    <multiple>true</multiple>
  </property>
</properties>
```

Comment: There's no easy way to do that, what are you trying to achieve? Is adding that aspect by some other means an option (example, through Node Behaviours rather than through the model definition itself)?

Answer (score 0):

Never update the out-of-the-box Alfresco content models. You are asking for trouble.

In this case, extend the content model with your own content model in its own namespace, then use it to define a new aspect that has the property you need, then add that aspect to the object instances as needed.